# Are there any ways to make \longrightarrow bigger and place it in the centre of two diagrams?

Tags: formatting, ytableau, youngtab

Might be a simple fix, might not, but I've been agonising over it for a while.

I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}
\ydiagram{7,7,7,7,7,0,6,4,3,2,1}
\,
$\longrightarrow$
\,
\ydiagram{7,7,7,7,7,6,4,3,2,1}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me:
[image]

Ideally, I'd like the arrow to be larger and centered vertically. Maybe the problem lies where I am using Youngs diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}
$\vcenter{\hbox{\ydiagram{7,7,7,7,7,0,6,4,3,2,1}}}
\,
\xrightarrow{\hspace{1cm}}
\,
\vcenter{\hbox{\ydiagram{7,7,7,7,7,6,4,3,2,1}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]